# using for loop for a textbox in selenium C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    Driver.Instance.Find Element(By.Id("id of element")).Send Keys("auto"+i);
}
```

I used this code but it does not work
1 to 10 numbers are printing in one attempt

I am searching for the code which dynamically increment in each run with out changing the sendkeys values again and again

Comment: Please clarify what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. Are you trying to Enter the value in 10 different Edit Boxes in a single run or you are trying to enter different values in same Edit box in multiple runs (If so you can use random class to generate random integers which will generate different values in different runs).

```
Random random = new Random();
int i = random.Next(0, 10);

Driver.Instance.Find Element(By.Id("id of element")).Send Keys("auto"+i);
```

You can increase the bucket `random.Next(0, 10);   to some random.Next(0, 100);` to decrease the

probability

of having same no in 10 runs.

Comment: I am trying to enter different values in same Edit box in multiple runs

Comment: when i used this random it was taking always same numbers Example- in third run it was again taking first run number

Answer (score 0):

```
   Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
   Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("tbReportName"))
        .SendKeys("report"+DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

OR

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("tbReportName"))
        .SendKeys("report" + guid.ToString());
```